# What data from Google Analytics is available in Marketing Cloud - and how to query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

A client has purchased the Google Analytics 360 license from Google.

And so, we have integrated Google Analytics (Not GA 360) to Marketing Cloud. Great!

Before we go the GA360 path, is there a way we can harvest the data that comes back from GA (e.g. via SQL queries to put it in DEs?) Any documentation around that?

Maybe new data is available via Data Views?

On the surface, it seems like this integration is mostly 1-way (adding UTMs consistently, which we were doing before manually), unless one purchases Analytics 360 from Marketing Cloud as well.

Adding up quotes we received both on the Google side and the Marketing Cloud side, the ask is for over $250,000 USD yearly on licenses only.

- What can be done with the license we currently have on the Google side and the GA "regular" connector running? Reports/Segmentation from Marketing Cloud?
- What will be improved if the client adds GA 360 license beyond what we see in JB Dashboard videos?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slide with the difference between GA Free and GA360 integration:

[image]

So GA free adds the UTM string for Journeys and also provides some analytics

There are no additional Data views.

GA360 does provide an audience imported into SFMC from GA360 to use as an entry source for a journey.

Comment: @EasyE, appreciate your answer. As I understand it, the short answer is: No data is available to query on neither versions AND No data is available for new Reporting in Marketing Cloud except the Out-of-the-box Dashboard in JB? If this is true, it's very disappointing, especially at this price point. Would have expected new Report Types in Analytics Builder or at least new Data Extensions/Data Views.